# Could not convert from brace-enclosed initializer list to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I saw a lot of similar questions, but I don't think I saw quite the same one. It's pretty basic. Some code from my lecturer is failing to compile, and I distilled the problem to this test case:

```
void foo(vector<int> v) {
}

void fooUsage() {
    foo({0, 1, 2});
}
```

This fails with:

`could not convert '{0, 1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<int>`

*Note: It works on GCC 5.0.0 20141228 but fails on my GCC 4.7.1 (tdm-1).*

Sorry if this is too basic but I don't know C++11 very well.

Comment: Ermm... missing compiler support in that version, or bug?

Comment: I believe GCC 4.7.1 has incomplete support for c++11 features such as this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I only needed to add `-std=c++11` to the gcc command line.

Note: I was mistakenly thinking that this is on by default, since I was also getting some warnings like this:

`extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]`

See how it says "enabled by default"? That's what was misleading me.

Comment: I had to add this flag even though my g++/gcc version was 5.4.0. Guess they did something and the flag must be added again!

Answer (score 6):

This is a [known bug that was fixed in gcc 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53361#c6).